# glossaries formatting bleed

Tags: glossaries

I've got an issue with the `glossaries` package. I've defined acronyms e.g. as

```
\newacronym{pl}{{\sc pl}}{Plural}
```

These work fine, with the small caps and all. The problem is this: if I reference acronyms (with `\acrshort`) in the main text of the document, the small caps continues from that point to the end of the document. It works mostly fine inside environments (in this case, `gb4e`'s `\ex` environment) - the small caps does still bleed a bit, but nothing that can't be worked around. I've tried following `\acrshort` with text in a `\textnormal` command, which works fine, but the small caps resumes at the end of the environment.

For example, with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{acr}{{\sc acr}}{Acronym}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

Text text 
\acrshort{acr} 
text text

\end{document}
```

the first two 'text's are normal, 'acr' is small caps, and the two 'text's after it are small caps.

Is this a bug in `glossaries`, or am I just doing something wrong? Is there any way around it without putting my entire document inside `\textnormal`?

Comment: Surely you shouldn't use `\sc`. Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Edited. Am I just not aware of a better small caps command?

Comment: `\sc` is deprecated. Use `\scshape` to switch to small-caps indefinitely (until end of group or you change the shape). Use `\textsc{pl}` to just change the shape of `pl`. Or use `\normalfont` or `\upshape` when you want to switch back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want *all* short forms of acronyms are in small caps; for this you want to set an option for `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}

\begin{document}

Text \acrlong{acr} text
\acrshort{acr}
text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If only some acronyms are desired in small caps (but I can't think why), then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{acr}{\textsc{acr}}{Acronym}

\begin{document}

Text \acrlong{acr} text
\acrshort{acr}
text text

\end{document}
```

Note that `\sc` is a deprecated command and has been for more than twenty years, since LaTeX2e has been released.

Comment: ...how in the world did I learn `\sc` then...? Anyway, thank you for your answer! If I need the acronyms to appear in small caps in the glossary as well, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Oh, never mind, it was a glossary format question. No further issues, thank you!